# PayPal ClassicAPI SDK for Android

Tags: android, paypal

I integrated this library https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK to my Application. Sandbox works fine, but production fails when I try to pay directly.

PayPal manual explain this reason. I can't use REST Api for direct payments in my country. But I can use Classic API.

So I registered application here https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications and got Sandbox ID and Live App ID.

But what next? If I use this Sandbox ID, PayPal SDK says that it's not right ID. As I understand PayPal SDK tries to use REST API automatically. But how I can use it for Classic API?

Googling this problem gets me to this page http://paypal.github.io/sdk/, but there's no Android library (Android tab exists, but useless).

How to connect Classic API by PayPal SDK?

Answer (score 1):

The PayPal Android SDK (Native) is built on top of REST APIs, and does not include any classic APIs in it.

To implement classic APIs on an Android device, you may want to setup the server side SDK (in whatever programming language you prefer, and obtain server SDKs from http://paypal.github.io/sdk/), and use the webview controller in your APP to load the server pages.

PayPal will be adaptive to mobile device resolutions so that there's no extra API codings required on the APP side.